# namespace in xslt placed in root tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces, saxon

I have an XSLT in which I have defined a function.
The transformer says that any function must have it's namespace, so I declared a dummy namespace in the head of the XSLT, but now this namespace appears also in the root tag of the output!
Can't guess how to avoid this...

Example:

input.xml

```
<something>
     <mytag> test </mytag>
</something>
```

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://function" version="2.0" >

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:function name="fn:trim" >
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($pStr,'^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="something">
    <root><xsl:value-of select="fn:trim(mytag)" /></root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:fn="http://function">test</root>
```

It's the `xmlns:fn="http://function"` in the `<root>` tag that I'd like to remove from my output.
Doesn't know if it matter, but I'm using Saxon-HE-9.4.

Comment: On a side note, if you want your function to return the string value computed by your `replace` call then use `<xsl:sequence select="replace($pStr,'^\s*(.+?)\s*$', '$1')"/>` as with `<xsl:value-of ` you return a text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://function" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fn">`. Also note that `fn` is usually used for the XPath function namespace so you might want to use a different prefix to avoid confusion by any users of your code.